# Testing compiled TypeScript with Karma and Jasmine from a JS test file

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, requirejs, karma-jasmine

I have a project with the following structure:

```
build
- out.js
spec
- foo.spec.js
- bar.spec.js
src
- foo.ts
- bar.ts
```

The two .ts files are built down into `out.js`. In my `.spec.js` files, I want to be able to reference `out.js` easily.

When using Karma/Jasmine in pure JS projects, I simply use RequireJS, and wrap my test files in a `define(['a'], function(a) { ... });` file. Then, in `a.js`, the contents would be wrapped like this:

```
define([], function() {
    Foo.prototype. .......
    Foo.prototype. .......

    return Foo; 
});
```

However, because out.js will be build by the TypeScript compiler, and therefore cannot be wrapped in the `define(...)` block, I am unable to correctly import it with RequireJS.

---

To clarify:

With handwritten JS, such as below, I can import it into my test files fine:

```
define([], function() {
    function Bla() { }
    Bla.prototype.hi = function () {
        return "hey";
    };
    return Bla;
});
```

With similar JS, but built with the TypeScript compiler and therefore missing the `define([])` wrapper, I simply get `undefined` when I import it into my tests.

```
var Bla = (function () {
    function Bla() { }
    Bla.prototype.hi = function () {
        return "hey";
    };
    return Bla;
})();
```

How can I either configure the TypeScript compiler to wrap my compiled classes in the `define()` wrapper, or how can I configure my tests to import the class without it being wrapped in a `define()` wrapper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should to use ["--module amd"](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Compiler-Options) parameter

in visual studio 2015: Project/"your project" properties/Typescript Building/module system/amd

and next:

bla.ts:

```js
function Bla() {
    
}
Bla.prototype.hi = function () {
    return "hey";
};
export = Bla;
```

bla.js:

```js
define(["require", "exports"], function (require, exports) {
    function Bla() {
    }
    Bla.prototype.hi = function () {
        return "hey";
    };
    return Bla;
});
```